# Acknowledge the JmsMessage with MessageConverter in spring-jms

Tags: jms, spring-jms

I am using jmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert() method in spring-jms. This method returns the converted object (Person) but if i used Client Acknowledge then how can i acknowledge the message in this case.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because you don't have access to the `Message`.

Use `receive()`; then call `messageConverter.fromMessage(message)` (e.g. on a `SimpleMessageConverter`) yourself to do the conversion.

**EDIT**

However you really shouldn't do that because the session will either be closed when `receive()` returns (or returned to a cache, in which case some other user might ack your message).

It's better to use `jmsTemplate.execute()` with a `SessionCallback` and only exit the callback after the message has been ack'd.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can we pass the Jms Message refernce in Custom Object and acknowledge it later. ?

Comment: Thanks for edit @Gary. its really helpful. Actually my requirement is to receive up to 50 messages and acknowledge them one by one based on there business logic. Does jmsTemplate.execute() will work in this scenario ?

Comment: You can do whatever you want within the scope of the `SessionCallback.doInJms()` method.

Comment: Hey, i know its a bit late to post a comment, Just one thing to clarify. How client ack. works with spring jms does it mean that in same session if i consume 5 messages and ack for one then all 4 will be also ack or we have an option to ack individual message. Would be great if you can provide any example or doc refrence which explains the same for spring jms

Comment: It's part of the JMS spec and not special to Spring - google `jms specification` and look at section 4.4.13 (of the 2.0 spec). `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE - With this option, a client acknowledges a
message by calling the message’s acknowledge method. Acknowledging a
consumed message automatically acknowledges the receipt of all messages
that have been delivered by its session.`